# Share X Discord problem. How do I make the link not disappear?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperlink, discord

Hello I got a short and simple question. How do I make my link NOT disappear whenever I send a sharex link to my friends on Discord so it shows the link and the image. (Im hosting my own sharex server)

Comment: make the response an embed imo, will look better than a separate image and link and also allows for more data to be shown, such as the date or file size

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that? @joeycrash135

Comment: lemme find you a link to help, check back in 5min

Comment: `discord guide to doing it vanilla` https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview
`This is how I do it personally as it gives the most control over your code

Comment: `npm discord.js-easy-embed` https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-easy-embed?activeTab=readme

Comment: `google fu is on the money today. Discord Embed Builder` https://autocode.com/tools/discord/embed-builder/
`this can be useful if its discord.js 12+, otherwise just use it to pre design your embed`